# How do I remove non UTF-8 characters from a String?

Tags: ruby, string, utf-8

I need to remove non UTF-8 characters from a string. Here is the snap of the text.

[image]

This is how it looks like when I open the string in NPP, and then set the encoding to UTF-8:

[image]

I think the `ACK` and `FF` are non UTF-8 characters.

I tried `str.scrub` as well as `str.encode`. Neither of them seems to work. `scrub` returns the same result, and `encode` results in an error.

Comment: Can you explain which characters are "non UTF-8" and why you believe that to be the case?

Comment: If you see the screenshot attached, I think the first character is non UTF-8. Also, the arrow symbol towards the left. When I copied and pasted the string here, the SO site automatically discarded those. So, please refer the screenshot.

Comment: Well, all characters in a UTF-8 string are UTF-8 characters. It would be invalid otherwise. And because codepoints 0-127 are the same in ASCII and UTF-8, it also contains [ACK](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0006/index.htm) and [FF](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000C/index.htm). Maybe you want to remove control characters or non-printable characters. What is your expected result?

Comment: I have a problem definition that says "Read X bytes from /dev/urandom and remove all non UTF-8 characters". Maybe, it means to remove the non-printable characters.

Comment: UTF-8 characters consist of one to four _bytes_. Not every byte (or byte sequence) is valid UTF-8. On the other hand, not every UTF-8 character is printable or printable on its own.

Comment: You need to clarify your question. What, *precisely* do you mean by "non UTF-8 character"? UTF-8 can encode all of Unicode, so the only characters that cannot be encoded in UTF-8 are the ones which are not in Unicode. However, Ruby only deals in Unicode, so there is no such thing as a character that cannot be encoded in UTF-8 in Ruby. Besides, UTF-8 is not a character set, so the very idea of a "UTF-8 character" or a "non UTF-8 character" is non-sensical anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have a few problems.

The biggest is that a Ruby String stores arbitrary bytes along with a supposed encoding, with no guarantee that the bytes are valid in that encoding and with no obvious reason for that encoding to have been chosen. (I might be biased as a heavy user of Python 3. We would never speak of "changing a string from one encoding to another".)

Fortunately, the editor did not eat your post, but it's hard to see that. I'm guessing that you decoded the string as Windows-1252 in order to display it, which only obscures the issue.

Here's your string of bytes as I see it:

```
>> s = "\x06-~$A\xA7ruG\xF9\"\x9A\f\xB6/K".b
=> "\x06-~$A\xA7ruG\xF9\"\x9A\f\xB6/K"
>> s.bytes
=> [6, 45, 126, 36, 65, 167, 114, 117, 71, 249, 34, 154, 12, 182, 47, 75]
```

And it does contain bytes that are not valid UTF-8.

```
>> s.encoding
=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
>> String::new(s).force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8).valid_encoding?
=> false
```

We can ask to decode this as UTF-8 and insert � where we encounter *bytes* that are not valid UTF-8:

```
>> s.encode('utf-8', 'binary', :undef => :replace)
=> "\u0006-~$A�ruG�\"�\f�/K"
```

Comment: I think this is what I need. But what is that binary for? I see similar results with and without it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. It's synonymous with ASCII_8BIT, and I'm using it for clarity in case the encoding of `s` had changed on me. The docs give three forms of the `encode` method and I couldn't really tell which invocation was needed.

Comment: This example helped me too. I would omit the 'binary' argument unless the intention is to change the encoding from utf-8 to binary (ASCII_8BIT). The docs indicate that adding it "returns a copy of str transcoded from src_encoding to dst_encoding" https://apidock.com/ruby/String/encode.